# How to translate url requests using pycurl to python-requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, pycurl

I would like to modify following code to run use 'requests' module.
I have the following code which is working on a website:

```
def post(url, message, key, sign):

    curl = pycurl.Curl()
    curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
    curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
    curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
    buf = cStringIO.StringIO()
    curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
    curl.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, message)
    curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Key:' + key,
                                'Sign:' + (sign)])
    curl.perform()
    response = buf.getvalue()
    buf.close()
    return response
```

I tried accessing the website with requests and got rejected on invalid request values using following code:

```
def post(url, message, key, sign):
    import requests
    session = requests.session()
    session.headers = {'Key': key, 'Sign': sign}
    response = session.post(url, message)
    return response
```

What am I doing wrong that these methods don't behave the same?

Thank you.

Comment: You should add your traceback. If it's something related to the ssl certif then try with session.post(url, message, verify=False)

Comment: I have no traceback as there's not python failure.
The error is returned from the website...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Pycurl:

```
POST /post HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PycURL/7.32.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:4000
Accept: */*
Key:key
Sign:sign
Content-Length: 3
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

foo
```

With requests:

```
POST /post HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:4000
Accept-Encoding: identity
Content-Length: 3
Key: key
Sign: sign

foo
```

There are several differences which could lead to your error:

- Missing `User-Agent` and `Accept` headers. This is because you *overwrite* the `session.headers` attribute which contains those default headers. Try this instead:

  `session.headers.update({'Key': key, 'Sign': sign})`
- Missing `Content-Type` header. I think you passed a string as the `message` parameter.
  Requests doesn't know that this is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and therefore  doesn't set the relevant header.
  Either:

  - Set the header yourself
  - Better: pass requests a dictionary of your parameters. They will be encoded and declared correctly